# How to add the level tag in Promtail config

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I’m using grafana loki to compose dashboards.
I need to group the logs by level to create the graph but in the details of the logs I can not see the level label:
[image: level without label]

my logs are like this:

```
2021-05-31 14:23:00.005  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] AssociationService       : Scheduler Association finish at 31-05-2021 02:23:00
```

There is a way to extrapolate the level and associate it to the label "level"?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use the [regex](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/regex/) stage:

```
- job_name: my-job
  pipeline_stages:
  - regex: 
      # extracts only log_level from the log line
      expression: '\s+(?P<log_level>\D+)\s.*'
  - labels:
      # sources extracted log_level as label 'level' value
      level: log_level
```

the expression above matches only `log_level`, but you may add more named capture groups and use them in the same way
i.e.

```
^(?P<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s+(?P<log_level>\S+)\s(?P<rest>.*)$
```

or less strict:

```
(?P<time>\S+\s\S+)\s+(?P<log_level>\D+)\s(?P<rest>.*)
```

match `time`, `log_level` and the `rest` of the line an extract them for later use.

check [regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/dx1Fcf/2)